# Spring Context in an EJB Module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, ejb-3.2

I'm currently in the making of an EJB Module, which could not be complete without persistence.

My initial instinct led me to use Spring Boot, since it has some wild implementations of how one could use JPA and to be honest, I'm kinda spoiled.

However, I couldn't really get Spring up and running in my EJB Module. I created the usual class with the *public static void main(String[])* method, but my fear, that this method never runs became reality and using a `@PostConstruct` method to initialize Spring sounds ridiculous.

How can I initialize Spring Boot on an EJB module? Should I make another module and somehow refer to that from my EJBs? How can I do that? Is it something that people actually do, or should I just get my lazy back-side down in front of the computer and learn *"proper"* JPA?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you used spring boot, then thats not EJB (plain). @PostConstruct is not spring specific, but EJB specific.

Comment: that's the reason why I wanted to use @PostConstruct. Because I can make a (at)Singleton (at)Startup EJB, which initializes Spring

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `SpringBootServletInitializer` to get Spring online inside container.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy

Comment: I have my war with spring boot fine. The EJB is not a web application tho